# google-api-php-client apiAuthException refreshing OAuth2

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api

I'm developing a PHP script to display a page with some charts and stats about my Analytics profile. I'm sending 3 or 4 ajax asynchronous calls to the server; the server then fetch data using **google-api-php-client** . There are about 10 requests to Google for each page refresh.

The problem is i'm getting totally random exceptions from the api:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error
>   refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: ' in apiOAuth2.php on line 242

One time i successfully get the data, one time not. This is very annoying because i cannot find **why**. **What could be? The asynch calls maybe?**

User quota is set to 1000 requests/second just to be sure. Eventually i get 'User quota exceded' from the api, something quite impossible.

Comment: Is your 2-step verification for your Google Account turned off? It throws that error if you are trying to access you GA account through PHP-API but have the 2-step turned on.

Comment: @jbloom1704 thanks for the tip. I'm near to solve the bug. I think that's my bad: at each request the access token (offline) may expire and it will be replaced with a new access token that i need to write back to my store as soon as the call ends. I think that this is the problem: reading the old access token from the file!

Comment: Nice, may I ask why are you using Oauth in a PHP based API for GA? Seems to me that you can simply use this back end strength (script) to accomplish secure calls without any sort of authorization. I mean, thats the reason I resorted to it.

Comment: @jbloom1704 yes i'm using OAuth, i force the user to login into google and authorize my application and then i store the access token into an ecrypted file (updated if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to myself because i found the problem (was my bad):

- I store the access token into an encrypted file
- Even if the access token should be *offline* it's **not really offline**: it expires but contains a *refresh token* that APIs will send to get a new fresh access token
- The new access token should be saved again into the file (i save it into `__destruct()` method of my wrapper class) and used for the next request (i was not saving it!)